# How to throw away the original collection once the Immutable version is created using Google Guava?

Tags: java, guava, immutability

I have a map as below and once I get the immutable version of the original map, I don't need the original one anymore. Is there a way to have the GC recycle it?

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("1", "one");
map.put("2", "two");
map.put("3", "three");

ImmutableMap<String, String> IMMUTABLE_MAP = ImmutableMap.copyOf(map);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the Map eligible for garbage collection by not having any references to it anymore. This will automatically happen when `map` goes out of scope. If that is "too late" for you, you could explicitly assign `null` to `map`.

Either way, the actual garbage collection happens in the background when the JVM feels like it.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it'll automatically goes away. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is right, but what you should try to do is to use

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> map =
         ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
    .put("1", "one")
    .put("2", "two")
    .put("3", "three")
    .build();
```

The builder is optimized for what it does and you can often write it all in a single expression.

---

Even much better is

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    "1", "one",
    "2", "two",
    "3", "three");
```

which works for up to four key-value pairs.